# Primality check change that seemed optimization turned out to be pessimization in Haskell

Tags: performance, haskell, primes

I wrote two functions to check if a number is prime in Haskell:

```
prime :: Int -> Bool
prime 0 = False
prime 1 = False
prime 2 = True
prime n | even n = False
prime n = all (\x -> n `rem` x /= 0) [3,5..intSqrt]
  where intSqrt = (floor . sqrt . fromIntegral) n

prime2 :: Int -> Bool
prime2 0 = False
prime2 1 = False
prime2 n = all (\x -> n `rem` x /= 0) [2..intSqrt]
  where intSqrt = (floor . sqrt . fromIntegral) n
```

The first version should, in average  do  half the calculations of the second one, because even numbers are skipped, but it turns out that the second version that seems slower is almost 2x faster! I include Terminal sessions timings verbatim.

Prime 1 version:

```
$ ghc -O2 prime.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( prime.hs, prime.o )
Linking prime ...
$ time ./prime
142913828922

real    0m4.617s
user    0m4.572s
sys 0m0.040s
```

Now I use change the program to make use of the prime2 version:

```
$ ghc -O2 prime.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( prime.hs, prime.o )
Linking prime ...
$ time ./prime
142913828922

real    0m2.288s
user    0m2.268s
sys 0m0.020s
$
```

The code in `main` is simply:

```
main :: IO()
main = print $ sum $ filter prime2 [1..2000000]
```

Why is the second version faster if it does twice the number of modolus?

Comment: I can't reproduce it, `prime` is 2x faster then `prime2` for me (ghc-7.10.1)

Comment: @Yuras Are you compiling with -O2? (My version of GHC is different:`Glasgow Haskell Compiler, Version 7.6.3, stage 2 booted by GHC version 7.6.3`

Comment: Yes, I'm compiling with `-O2`. Different compiler versions can explain different behavior though.

Comment: I don't understand a 2x slowdown, but keep in mind that `even` is doing a modulo operation as well -- so there's no reason to believe the second should be twice as fast! (It potentially *could* be twice as fast, if the compiler notices that there's a monomorphic modulo by a constant and replaces it by very fast bit operations. Modern GHCs should notice this -- especially with `-fllvm` -- but I guess it's by no means guaranteed.)

Answer (score 0):

As Daniel pointed out in comments, asking `even n` would do a `mod` operation just like in the second version. Furthermore, it would be the first case hit in the second version. So the second version has fewer case branches but the same efficiency. Remember Haskell is a non-strict language, so all the other `mod` operations won't get forced if the first already returns `True`.